# Existence of fundamental solutions to general linear PDE with const. coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, distribution-theory

Let $p(D)$ be a nontrivial polynomial with $D=-i\partial$ such that
$$
p(D) = \sum_{a} c_aD^a
$$
for a multiindex $a$ and constants $c_a$. I was wondering how and if we can prove that a fundamental solution $u^* \in \mathscr{D'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (in the space of distributions) given by $p(D)u^* = \delta$ exists.

I thought that we can start by approximating $\delta \in \mathscr{D}'$ by smooth, compactly supported functions since $\mathscr{D}\equiv C^\infty_c$ is dense in $\mathscr{D}'$. But then how do we show that this will converge in the limit?

Another possibility could be by Fourier analysis, but I am not sure how to progress with a proof. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Eventually this holds as there is a theorem for it in Hörmander's book *Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I* (see Theorem 7.3.10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible approaches is, indeed, to consider Fourier transform. After applying this transform you will get (up to some non-interesting normalisation constants) an equation
$$p(\xi) \hat u = 1.$$

Now you need to show that (with some reasoning involving, eventually, principal values) $\frac{1}{p(\xi)}$ is a tempered distribution. Main points are that on infinity this fraction is bounded, and that near roots of $p$ the fraction "behaves well".

After that, you can apply an inverse FT to get your tempered distribution $u$.

Comment: Yes, I actually went that far myself, but  I wasn't sure how to progress with the proof. Eventually, I edited the question as I found that there is a theorem for this in Hörmander's book.

Comment: Do we know  what happens for (O/P)DE with non-constant coefficients? Does the fundamental solution exist?

Comment: @pluton I think John's PDE book and the volumes of Hörmander treat this kind of problem.